# Using jenkins docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am preparing and docker image based on jenkins:lts. To setup the initial configuration I use the init.groovy.d scripts, but:

- is that the best option?
- is there a way to prevent those scripts to run again in the second start? (I do not want to overwrite any change after init)

Comment: What does their documentation say?

Comment: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md not much

Answer (score 0):

I end up using a file as a status marker

```
// Skip exec. if the init already run once, do not overwrite ui config
final File status = new 
File("${System.getenv("JENKINS_HOME")}/init.groovy.d/uk-config.status")
if (status.exists()) {
  logger.info("First init already run")
  return
}
status.createNewFile()
```

It creates a file the first time the script runs and it checks if the file exists and prevent execution the second one.